# Bitwise operator predence

Tags: language-design, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence

A gotcha I've run into a few times in C-like languages is this:

```
original | included & ~excluded   // BAD
```

Due to precedence, this parses as:

```
original | (included & ~excluded)   // '~excluded' has no effect
```

Does anyone know what was behind the original design decision of three separate precedence levels for *bitwise* operators? More importantly, do you agree with the decision, and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operators have had this precedence since at least [C](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

I agree with the order because it is the same relative order as the relative order of the arithmetic operators that they are most similar to (`+`, `*` and negation).

You can see the similarity of `&` vs `*`, and `|` vs `+` here:

```
A  B | A&B A*B | A|B A+B 
0  0 |  0   0  |  0   0
0  1 |  0   0  |  1   1
1  0 |  0   0  |  1   1
1  1 |  1   1  |  1   2
```

The similarity of bitwise not and negation can be seen by this formula:

```
~A = -A - 1
```

Comment: Yes, in logics ∧ also has higher precedence than ∨ for the same reason.

Comment: You could note that `^` is below `*` and above `|` which is somewhat arbitrary but reasonable. The unfortunate choice in C is to have the binary bitwise operators lower in precedence than the comparison operators requiring expressions like `(status & MASK) != MASK` to require the extra parenthesis.

Comment: This all makes sense, except that distributivity also holds in reverse: `A|B & A|C == A | (B&C)`. But I would say the use cases for bitwise ops are *far* different than the use cases for boolean ops (whose precedence makes perfect sense to me). Would you look down on a language who defined all bitwise op precedences to be the same? (and why?)

Comment: @zildjohn01: Good point, I have removed the distributivity one. Regarding your question - would I look down on such a language? I'd find it very unintuitive but adding in the extra parentheses rarely makes the code less readable so it wouldn't be a huge problem if I know about it (and I'd probably learn it the hard way - by writing code that doesn't work and debugging it). If a language use illogical (in my opinion) order of precedence then I'd immediately be on my guard, wondering what other "problems" I might run into with that language. It's related to the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: You convinced me with POLA. Sometimes it's hard to draw the line between what changes are OK to make (such as what @RBerteig mentioned), and what changes are too much.

Comment: @zildjohn01, I've never tried to figure out the rationale behind the precedence inversion between bitwise and compare. I assume there was a rationale, because even 1st ed. K&R calls it out as a source of error. By then, it was too late to fix, of course, and almost thirty years later is *way* too late to fix it. IMHO, if a language is "sufficiently C-like", then its operators should follow C precedence or you risk cognitive dissonance. I don't exactly what I mean by "sufficiently", of course.

Comment: Very true, but I'm willing to take a chance because (1) `a & (b == c)` won't compile in a statically-typed language (you'll find the error quick), (2) common sense would rank operators that result in a boolean lower than those that don't, and (3) it's so often cited as a design error.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Mark Byers' answer, in boolean algebra (used extensively by electrical engineers to simplify logic circuits to the minimum number of gates and to avoid race conditions), the tradition is that bitwise AND takes precedent over bitwise OR.  C was just following this established tradition.  See http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Combining_Operations :

> Just as in ordinary algebra, where
>   multiplication takes priority over
>   addition, AND takes priority (or
>   precedence) over OR.