# Unexpected results from bitwise operation why (1 | 1 & 2) gives 1 instead of 2?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Cannot get this simple calculation straight using visual studio 2010

```
std::cout<<(1 | 1 & 2);    

//gives the value 1, was expecting 2 since 1 | 1 = 2 , the & 2   gives 2


std::cout<<( (1 | 1) & 2); 

//gives the value 0, why is this different from above?
```

Comment: 1|1 does not = 2.  This ain't arithmetic

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730539/bitwise-operator-predence

Comment: Please take a peek at operator precedence. And Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP: Of course it is arithmetic.  But it is not addition, even though some notations for inclusive-OR use a `+` symbol.

Answer (score 4):

**First case:**

1 & 2  // since `&` has higher precedence than `|`

```
 01
&10
----
 00
```

and OR the result with 1,

```
   1
OR 0
-----
   1
```

**In second case**

1 | 1

```
   01
OR 01
----
   01
```

and AND the result with 2,

```
   01
&  10
-----
   0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because the `&` operator has higher precedence than the `|` operator so

```
1 | 1 & 2
```

is evaluated as

```
1 | (1 & 2)
```

so

```
1 & 2 = 0
```

and

```
1 | 0 = 1
```

hence your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`1 | 1` is 1. Why do you think it should be 2?

`1 & 2` is 01 & 10 in binary, which is 00 - hence the zero you get.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things happening here:

1. Bitwise AND (`&`) has a higher precedence (i.e., is effectively evaluated first) than Bitwise OR(`|`).
2. `1 | 1` is `1`, not `2`.

Answer (score 0):

1 | 1 gives 1
x | x always will give you x

1 | & 2 is equivalent to 1 | (1 & 2)

because & is like * for +
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

P.S. here is an online calculatore
http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/?data_type=10&number1=1&number2=1&operator=OR